# Angular2 - Can I pick and choose modules to use?

Tags: module, angular

I really want to get going learning and using Angular2, but in its current state its quite bloated, which I find quite off-putting.

Is it possible to use Angular2 in a modular way? Instead of using the whole framework can I just pick modules like components and directives while leaving out other things such as http, routing, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure!

For this, you don't need to import corresponding JS files:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script> <--- Don't use this one
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script> <--- Don't use this one
```

Comment: Are those all the modules?

Comment: For Angular2 core, yes! angular2-polyfills (reflect-metadata, zone.js), system.src.js (module system), Rx.js (observables), angular2.dev.js (Angular2 core modules)